# How to get few select value using one jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My `html` page has select menus to select `usertype`, `min age` and `max age`. i need to select options and pass values to ajax as an array object. When i load the page `getAjax` function is working. but when i select any option on select menu, it is not working.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/search';

    var dataPara = {
      usertype: 1,
      ageSelectStart: 21,
      ageSelectEnd: 35
    };

    getAjax(ajaxUrl, dataPara); //working
    //following code is not working
    $("#usertypeSelect", "#ageSelect1", "#ageSelect2").change(function() {
      dataPara[$(this).attr('id')] = parseInt($(this).val());
      getAjax(ajaxUrl, dataPara);
    });

  });

function getAjax(URL, dataPara) {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    data: dataPara,
    dataType: "html",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(retdata) {
      $("#mainData").html(retdata);
    }
  });
} </script>
```

```html
<html>
<div class="side-menu-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <label>User type</label>
      <select id="usertypeSelect">
        <!-- options here-->
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Age</label>
      <select id="ageSelect1">
        <!-- options here-->
      </select>
      <label>To</label>
      <select id="ageSelect2">
        <!-- options here-->
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `$("#usertypeSelect, #ageSelect1, #ageSelect2").change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple selector you need to put all the selectors in a single quote.[**Here**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) is a link

```
$("#usertypeSelect,#ageSelect1,#ageSelect2").change(function() {
      // Rest of code
    });
```

Also initially `dataPara` object does not contain `ageSelect1` & `ageSelect2`. They will only be appended on there is a change in respective `select`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in jQuery, to select multiple classes/ID's in one line, they must still be all in the same set of quotes. So the line:

```
$("#usertypeSelect", "#ageSelect1", "#ageSelect2").change(function() {
```

Should instead read:

```
$("#usertypeSelect, #ageSelect1, #ageSelect2").change(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#usertypeSelect, #ageSelect1, #ageSelect2").on('change', function() {
    dataPara[$(this).attr('id')] = parseInt($(this).val());
    getAjax(ajaxUrl, dataPara);
});
```

Try this

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.